# How to use Robot.mouseMove() fix from openjdk?

Tags: java, mousemove, awtrobot

As per [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8196030) thread the bug is "resolved" and the fix is available [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/18f8e3b6f3b7) but I have no idea as to how to use it. I've tried copying over all .java files to my local project but I get errors related to missing Classes. There's also a C++ source file involved which I don't know what to do with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bug is fixed in the OpenJDK itself. So you need to update the OpenJDK on the machine which is running your app and that's it. Be sure to install a version that includes the fix.

Comment: Does installing the latest openJDK from [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html) on target machine guarantee my software (or at least the Robot.mousMove()) section will work correctly on it?

Comment: That depends on many things.  - Did they really fix the bug and did they test it well? - Are you using that method properly or is your code buggy, too ? - Does the OpenJDK version you install contain the bugfix mentioned above or not? 

The issue contains the Fixversion of OpenJDK and this and later versions should include the bugfix. If you are unsure create a account there and ask the developers of openJDK ;).